# Query XML with Linq to xml

Tags: xml

How to retrieve the value of the Element Customer, Result and Reason by using Linq To Access.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE CreateAccount>
  <CreateAccount>
  <Customer>tonytsund</Customer>
   <Result>Failed</Result>
   <Reason>Reseller/Password combination unknown</Reason>
   </CreateAccount>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
XElement xe = XElement.Load(ur xml);
    var CusValue = from a in xe.Elements("Customer")
                   select a.Value;
    var ResultValue= from a in xe.Elements("Result")
                      select a.Value;
    Var ReasonValue= from a in xe.Elements("Reason")
                      select a.Value;
```